# How to use FreeCAD part library with A2Plus

Tags: cad, freecad

I want to know how to combine this effectivly. I know where the files are located and that I can include them into A2tech. The thing is, that as example the "pcb-terminal-block-female-1x2" from "Electronic Parts > Connectors > power-connectors" provides a sketch for drilling holes, but I do not understand how to utelize it. Sure, I can create the holes in my pcb part based on the sketch, but still need to manually add the parts in A2plus?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be related to 3D printing.

Comment: Yes not directly but I didn't found an CAD Stack Exchange. I know that it doesn't matter, that the project is 3D Printed related, but FreeCAD as a construction tool also used for 3D Printing so I thought it is the best available match

Comment: SE.Engineering might be the place to ask, there are a lot of [AutoCAD](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/autocad) questions there, so maybe FreeCAD too? See also [Where can questions that are purely about 3D modelling, or CAD, software be asked?](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/558/4762). Also [Which StackExchange site is for asking about AutoCAD?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243757/280335)